# Pronunciation of E in je, le, ce, ne, que

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, voyelles

Is the E in the end of monosyllabic words like je, le, ce, ne and que pronounced [ø] , [œ] or [ə] ? It seems I hear different sounds, depending on the sentence and on the speaker.

Examples:

- le garçon [lø]
- Il te le dit [lə]

Comment: IMHO, they should all be pronouced in the same way (I do). That said there are many different accents in France, and pronouciation may vary, but they should not. (quite like `é` sometimes pronouced `ai` when it should not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/ə/ is the pronunciation given by [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/le), so *in theory* it should be used. However, in practice, this may change to /ø/ or /œ/ depending on the speaker and the context in which the schwa appears. This is discussed in detail on [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_phonology#Schwa) Wikipedia. In particular:

> Fagyal, Kibbee & Jenkins (2006) state, more specifically, that it merges with /ø/ before high vowels and glides […] in phrase-final stressed position […] and that it merges with /œ/ elsewhere.
>
> […] Pronouncing [ə] as [œ] is a way to emphasise the syllable.

The exact pronunciation of the schwa is addressed in a number of academic papers, including in ["On the phonetic identity of French schwa  compared to /ø/ and /œ/"](http://lpp.in2p3.fr/IMG/pdf/fougeron-gendrot-burki-jel2007.pdf) by Fougeron, Gendrot, and Bürki.

> This variability in the phonetic identity of schwa has in fact been reported in many descriptions in the literature. Its pronunciation has been said to vary between [œ] and [ø] depending on speakers, varieties of French, and segmental contexts (Delattre 47, 64; Tranel 87, Valdman 70).