# lip-rounding of definite article?

Tags: prononciation

I am a native Indian speaker and I am having trouble determining the rounded quality of the masculine definite article.

**Is 'le' (such as in 'le pet') pronounced /lə/ or /lø/?**

Is it a regional difference? A syntactical difference?

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pronunciation of E in je, le, ce, ne, que](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36880/pronunciation-of-e-in-je-le-ce-ne-que)  Bienvenue sur French Language SE.

Comment: This related question on [Difference in pronunciation of /ø/, /ə/, and /œ/](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/46708/1893) has quite a helpful answer.